# Use Pandas to to read whitespace delimited triangular matrix with empty cells as zeros

Tags: python, pandas, data-munging

I'm trying to use pandas.read_table() to read a whitespace delimited lower triangular matrix from a text file. The zeros entries of the matrix are left blank.

```
    C1  C2  C3
R1   1
R2   2   3
R3   5   6   7
```

For now, I have the following ugly two step solution.

```
header = pd.read_table('test.txt', delim_whitespace=True, nrows=0)
names = list(header.columns.values)
names.insert(0, '')

df = pd.read_table('test.txt', delim_whitespace=True,
                        names=names, skiprows=1, index_col=0)
```

Which does give me what I want. Output:

```
    C1   C2  C3
R1  1   NaN NaN
R2  2   3.0 NaN
R3  5   6.0 7.0
```

Is there a "cleaner" way to do something similar?

Comment: what's the output of `pd.read_table('text.txt', delim_whitespace=True)`

Comment: I get ```ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 4, saw 4```

Comment: Why are you specifying `nrows=0`. You are opening a file and reading zero rows.

Comment: mad_: It's a hack so that I can read the header row. I could use 0 or 1 there doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: since we don't have access to your data, only experienced people will answer your question, so if it is urgent I'll figure a way to share your data

Comment: I'm not sure if we preserve the exact same structure, since I'm not sure if copy pasting from an html source preserves the same non printable characters from his source .txt file, including line breaks

Comment: Copy pasting does seem to give me the same structure as my local .txt file. However, if there's a recommended way to share a .txt file, I'd gladly do that.

Comment: maybe try [fixed width](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html)

Comment: it's because you have empty name of index, length of header doesn't match length of rows.

Comment: @Yuca: that woks perfectly. ```pd.read_fwf('test.txt', index_col=0)``` Gives me what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`pandas.read_fwf`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) to read a fixed width file

```
text = """\
    C1  C2  C3
R1   1
R2   2   3
R3   5   6   7"""

pd.read_fwf(pd.io.common.StringIO(text), index_col=0)

    C1   C2   C3
R1   1  NaN  NaN
R2   2  3.0  NaN
R3   5  6.0  7.0
```